# How do modern 4g smartphones handle their ip address?

Tags: internet, ip, isp, smartphone

I was wondering about how do modern mobile phones get their ip.
Have they all the same mechanis or are different for each isp? Do mobiles have static ip or it changes? How do companies identify mobile phones and smartphones over the internet?

Answer (score 3):

With little exception. They all use [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). They know whom is a (their) customer, and *which* customer; By their [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

The same is usually also true for ISPs, as well.